# Undefined variable: st_sel Laravel 8

Tags: database, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder, sql-query-store

I'm using Laravel 8, now im creating dashboard.blade to display the login user details. Im facing issue as that the query result array is not display in my blade page.

My controller code is,

```
public function student_board(){
        //dashboard session...
        if(session()->has('studid')){
            $data = session()->get('studid');
            $st_sel= DB::table('studs')
            ->join('users', 'studs.semail', '=', 'users.email')
            ->select('studs.sname','studs.semail')
            ->where('users.email','=',$data)
            ->get();
            return view('account')->with('stud', $st_sel);
        }
        else{
            return redirect('sreg')->with('fail','Login/Reg to Access..');
        }
    }
```

My blade code is,

```
                <div class="col-sm-4 invo-col">
                  From
                  @foreach($st_sel as $data)
                  <address>
                    <strong>Name: {{$data->sname}}</strong><br>
                    Email: {{$data->semail}} 
                  </address>
                  @endforeach
                </div>
```

My route is,

```
Route::get('/student-board',[usercontrol::class,'student_board'])->name('student-board');
```

Im getting st_sel is undefined, but im using with() function properly i think.
dont know where i made mistake.

Comment: `->with('stud', $st_sel)` You named it `stud`, use `@foreach($stud as $data)...`

Comment: yes its working @brombeer thank you so much